# BASH script to open xterm and continue executing

Tags: bash, xterm

I want to open a xterm with a ping scan how ever I don't want the script to halt until the xterm is closed.

I'm using

```
    xterm -hold -e ping localhost
```

The script looks like

```
    #!/bin/bash
    echo "hello"
    xterm -hold -e ping localhost
    echo "the script did not halt"
    echo "see the script is going and xterm is running at the same time"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just put it in the background with `&`:

```
xterm -hold -e ping localhost &
```

Comment: Thank you for that. Works great!